# MUI DataGrid NoResultsOverlay Custom Component Issues

Tags: material-ui

Buttons under the **NoResultsOverlay** or **NoRowsOverlay** component are not clickable due to absolute positioning and no z-index.

Also if the data grid is set to **autoHeight**, the overlay components are cut-off.

Code Sandbox link below to reproduce the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/customemptyoverlaygrid-demo-mui-x-forked-6hu6f6?file=/demo.js

The custom component gets wrapped by an absolutely positioned DIV with no z-index. Adding that fixes the issue.
But how to add it through componentProps or css is the question.
Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems fixing this issue is a work in progress. Here is [pull request](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/pull/5808) resuming the different issues about overlays

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem, adding  `style={{pointerEvents: "all"}}` it worked for a button. I guess this should also solve your problem